# StateProvider return to me iteraton undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

StateProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

// Prepares the dataLayer
export const StateContext = createContext();

// Wrap our app and provide the Data layer
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

// Pull information from the data layer
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
  basket: [],
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
      return {
        ...state,
        basket: [**your text**...state.basket, action.item],
      };
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

Proudct.js

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/Proudct.css'
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

function Proudct({ title, currency, price, rate, image }) {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const addToBasket = () => {
    // dispatch the item into the data layer
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
      item: {
        title: title,
        image: image,
        price: price,
        rate: rate,
      },
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className='proudct'>
      <p className='proudct--title'>{title}</p>
      <div className='proudct--price'>
        <small>{currency}</small>
        <strong>{price}</strong>
      </div>
      <span className='proudct--rate'>{rate}</span>
      <div className='proudct--image'>
        <img src={image} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={addToBasket} className='proudct--button'>Add to Basket</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Proudct;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom"
import Checkout from './compenets/Checkout';
import Home from './compenets/Home';
import reducer, { initialState } from './compenets/Reducer';
import { StateProvider } from './compenets/StateProvider';

const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true , element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "checkout",
        element: <Checkout />
      }
    ]
  }
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router ={routes} /> 
    <StateProvider initalState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
reportWebVitals();
```

Unhandled Thrown Error!
undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at Proudct

You can provide a way better UX than this when your app throws errors by providing your own errorElement props on `<Route\>`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You don't appear to be providing a context value to your app.

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={routes} /> 
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

There is no default context value:

```
export const StateContext = createContext(); // <-- default value is undefined
```

When consumers attempt to destructure the context value they can't since the context value they receive is undefined. There's nothing to iterate and destructure from.

```
const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue(); // <-- can't iterate undefined
```

## Solution

It's common, but not necessary, to provide a default Context value:

```
export const StateContext = createContext([
  { basket: [] }, // <-- object with expected properties and empty/default vlaues
  () => {}        // <-- "dispatch" function
]);
```

The Context provider still needs to wrap, and render, the ReactTree it's providing a value to.

The `StateProvider` component should wrap the `RouterProvider` component so the routes being rendered have a context provider above them in the ReactTree.

Example:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <RouterProvider router={routes} /> 
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for solving and explaining the problem